# Oracle SQL - join two tables + show unmatched results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

POSITION_TABLE

| Account | Security | Pos_Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 100 |
| 2 | B | 200 |

TRADE_TABLE

| Account | Security | Trade_Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 50 |
| 2 | C | 10 |

I want to join them in a way that matching rows are displayed as one row, but unmatching rows are also displayed, so standard LEFT JOIN wouldnt work.

Expected output:

| Account | Security | Pos_Quantity | Trade_Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 100 | 50 |
| 2 | B | 200 | 0 |
| 2 | C | 0 | 10 |

How do I do that?

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN. Or UNION ALL with GROUP BY.

Comment: To clarify - the scenario is much more complex and above I only put idea, I tried FULL OUTER JOIN, but it doesn't seem like it works with subquery added via WITH clause - this is how I set up TRADE_TABLE. I tried avoid UNION ALL, I thought it's ineffective here

Comment: UNION ALL with proper indexes shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Radek why don't you think a FULL OUTER JOIN won't work with a subquery defined in the WITH clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full outer join would work nicely here:

```
with position_table as (select 1 account, 'A' security, 100 pos_quantity from dual union all
                        select 2 account, 'B' security, 200 pos_quantity from dual),
        trade_table as (select 1 account, 'A' security, 50 trade_quantity from dual union all
                        select 2 account, 'C' security, 10 trade_quantity from dual)                   
select coalesce(pt.account, tt.account) account,
       coalesce(pt.security, tt.security) security,
       coalesce(pt.pos_quantity, 0) pos_quantity,
       coalesce(tt.trade_quantity, 0) trade_quantity
from   position_table pt
       full outer join trade_table tt on pt.account = tt.account
                                         and pt.security = tt.security
order by account,
         security;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d40cad3a6b6732f505fc72c90faba179) - note how you can see that the full outer join works just fine with subqueries defined in a where clause!

Comment: This is because Im moron :) and my WHERE condition from main query (positions_table) didnt allow for any entries from subquery  (trade_table) to appear :) Now I moved main query (positions_table) to subquery like I did with trade_table and I put WHERE conditions in these subqueries. After doing that I did simple main query to fetch data from both subqueries like you did and it works like a charm now!